# How to return a selected value from a database collection in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I have a database collection labeled `@joe`, and I am trying to pass the `id` variable into a link url path. This is in my `index.erb.html` file.

```
<%= select_tag "article", options_from_collection_for_select(@joe, 'id', 'title'), 
prompt: "Select Something" %>
```

In my `articles_controller.rb` file, I have

```
  def index
    @joe = Article.all
  end
```

I made a loop where it grabs each `id` number and passes it into the `article_url` path. I was wondering, in the dropdown box that I created above, when I select a certain value, I want to pass that value into the `article.id` variable. I'm having trouble with this and it outputs `x` amount of buttons.

```
<% @joe.each do |article| %>
    <%= button_to "SELECT", article_url(article.id), :method => 'get' %>
<% end %>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do this or if I can implement JavaScript or jQuery into this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

And here's the `rake routes` command results:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
  home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)        home#index
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
        root GET    /                            home#index
```

Comment: Solve that with Javascript (e.g jQuery). When the select changes value, then grab that value and update the button.

Comment: @dan-klasson I'm new to rails, so how can I implement jQuery into rails?

Comment: Should be there already. You should modify your question to describe exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @dan-klasson OK so I changed the question. Do you have any suggestions by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

ERB

```
<%= form_tag article_path do %>
  <%= select_tag "id", options_from_collection_for_select(@joe, 'id', 'title'), prompt: "Select Something", class: 'select' %>

  <%= button_tag 'SELECT', class: 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

JS

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  var path = $('form').attr('action');
  var articleId = $('.select').val();
  $.get([path, articleId].join('/'));
});
```

Comment: Of course. He just wants the id that will get submitted anyways. My bad.

Comment: @nbermudezs The fourth line doesn't work. I'm not sure how to make it go to a certain link to an article_path.

Comment: The fourth line of the code? That's an `end` xD, I don't think that isn't working. The absolute fourth line is your `select_tag`. Try deleting the `class: `. What error are you getting?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add the `method` to the form_tag. Will edit the answer

Comment: @nbermudezs I'm getting `http://0.0.0.0:3000/articles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&id=4&authenticity_token=mdxqBap61kZR3zti%2BB9NBxQW30SZlkbhcR4NxuiKn9zy8ycmKGza86tvP0QCQt7Wcck4DRln%2BvYieZb3Ozupvg%3D%3D` But it's the same page. It's supposed to be something like `http://0.0.0.0:3000/articles/1/` or `http://0.0.0.0:3000/2/` etc...

Also, I put `<%= form_tag article_path, :method => 'get' do %>` for the first line

Comment: @nbermudezs Do I just put that in the <script> tag? And I need to put a `do` in the `form_tag` otherwise there will be an error in the `end` tag.

Comment: You can put it in a `script` tag or change the first line to `$(document).on('click', '.button', function() {` and throw it in any js file in `app/assets/javascripts`